# Trying to do some XSLT magic on YouTube XML, running into some namespace issues

Tags: xml, xslt, youtube-api, xml-namespaces

So I'm trying to write an XSLT script that will transform the default RSS feed for a YouTube playlist into a more visually pleasing format.  I think I have the code more or less down, but I'm running into what I think is an issue with namespaces.

Basically, there's a `<yt:videoid>` and a `<media:description>` tag that my XSLT parser seems to choke on, and I'm not really sure how to fix it (neither namespace is ever defined in the original document).  My code looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="feed/entry">
    <item>
        <title><xsl:value-of select="title" /></title>
        <description>
        <![CDATA[<img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/{yt:videoid}/hqdefault.jpg">
        <br />
        <br />
        <xsl:value-of select="media:description">
        <br />
        <br />          
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/{yt:videoid}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>]]>
        </description>
        <link>http://www.youtube.com/watch?v={yt:videoid}</link>
        <guid isPermaLink="false">http://www.youtube.com/watch?v={yt:videoid}</guid>
        <pubDate><xsl:value-of select="updated" /></pubDate>
    </item>
```

When I run it, it compiles with a bunch of "Namespace prefix X on Y is not defined" errors, and anywhere that I included `{yt:videoid}` or `media:description` appears as plaintext rather than the appropriate value.

Another more minor issue is that the XML document is opened with

```
<feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/' xmlns:openSearch='http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/' xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005' xmlns:yt='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007' gd:etag='W/&quot;Ak8EQX47eCp7I2A9WhdSEkQ.&quot;'>
```

and it won't even parse unless I manually cut it down to `<feed>`.  Again, that's a much smaller issue, and I'd much prefer to solve the first one.  If anyone has any advice, I'd really appreciate it!

Adam

Comment: Try adding the xmlns:yt='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007' attribute to your <xsl:stylesheet> element. It looks like that you're trying to use elements in a different XML namespace and that's where things are choking on.

Comment: Your comment actually helped a lot.  I realized that I actually needed to include everything in that `feed` tag in both documents, so I included it in the `root` tag in the original document, and the `xsl` tag in the xslt document.  I can now get it to compile without errors, however wherever I try to use a namespace tag like `yt:videoid` or `media:description`, it still refuses to grab the value.  Any advice?

Comment: Any chance you can provide the XML document that you are trying to transform and your updated XSLT. I suspect that you have a problem with your select entries. (i.e. select="feed/entry" should be "atom:feed/atom:entry" if you've defined xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" in your <xsl:stylesheet> element.

Comment: Did you manage to make any progress on this?

Comment: Hey, sorry, I'm at home so I don't have access to the code at the moment.  However, I basically got it to the point where it would compile correctly by including all the namespace definitions in both documents.  The problem now is that 1) the `yt:videoid` and `media:description` return blank values, and 2) when I get that to work, I'm not sure how to append the `yt:videoid` to a YouTube url within an `a` tag, but hopefully I'll be able to take care of it tomorrow.  Let me know if you have any ideas for either of those, but your advice has already been super helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: Hey, so if you're still wondering, I solved it.  After getting all that namespace nonsense hammered out, the only thing that was causing hangups was that both `yt:videoid` and `media:description` were both contained within a `<media:group>` block that I didn't notice because 1) I'm an idiot and 2) YouTube's code is a mess.  Anyways, thanks for all your help!

Comment: Sounds good, we all make dumb mistakes like that :) do you mind if I summarize the answer so we can mark this question as answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarize the issue, the XSLT was missing the namespaces that is present in the XML. So, if the XML contains the following namespace:

```
xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/' 
xmlns:openSearch='http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/' 
xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'    
xmlns:yt='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007'
```

You'll need to add that into the  element as well. There's a good read below on understanding XML namespaces below:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302166.aspx